# Activating a SQL Server role

Tags: sql-server, roles

I'm searching for the exact syntax of the activation of a user role in SQL Server. The best description I found was:

```
ALTER USER userName  
     WITH <set_item> [ ,...n ]
```

But I'm not sure what does this mean in practice. Is this example correct syntactically?

```
ALTER USER sh 
    WITH DEFAULT ROLE dw_manager;
```

If not, can you give me a good example?

Comment: [GRANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173848.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have created your user and your role before - once you have that, you can use the [`sp_addrolemember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx) system stored procedure to make a user a member of a role (thus "activating" a user's role):

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'NameOfYourRoleHere', 'NameOfYourDatabaseUserHere'
```